# Styles on printing page generating by AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use AJAX to simply generator, but i have small problem with styles. I don't find solution of my problem.

I sending request into PHP file with AJAX, this returns HTML code. I getting on javascript and generating "print page". If page doesn't have styles - all is okey, but when i try adding styles with this method, script return white page without content.

```
$.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: "generate.php",
    data: {pid: pid},
}).done(function(data) {
    output = window.open('');
    output.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="offer.css" /></head><body>');
    output.document.write(data + '</body></html>');
    output.print();
});
```

PHP code just like this

```
<?php
$foo = "foo";
ob_start();
?>

<p><?php echo $foo; ?></p>

<?php 

$result = ob_get_flush();
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: @sasuero have you tried adding the style code instead of using a link to the style file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `write()` is used after an HTML document is fully loaded it deletes all existing HTML. So for multiple lines try it like this:

```
document.write(
   '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="offer.css" /></head><body>'
   + data + '</body></html>'
)
```